# how can I increase cpu quota on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to start 8 virtual machines with 4 cpu each and getting error
"ERROR: QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 24.0"

Documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas
says:
"Billable resource quotas are set by the application administrator in the Billing Settings tab of the Administration Console"

However, I can't find any such control in "Billings".

Any ideas how can I change this CPU limit?

Answer (score 15):

The docs you found are referring to the App Engine usage quotas which are separate from the Compute Engine quotas. Compute Engine quotas start out relatively small. Here are the [docs for Compute Engine quotas](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas).

Follow the instructions at [GCE Quota Increase](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746) to change the quota.

To view your current quotas, visit the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and click Compute Engine, then Quota.

Comment: Hi, the second link you wrote is deprecated. Could you please edit your answer to match the new link ? ==> https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746. Cheers

Answer (score 10):

You can now request the CPUs quota of Google Compute Engine at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Comment: This is working really nice. This should be the correct answer now